# iOS Facebook SDK - Post to Friends wall with Privacy value set to SELF not being set

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0, fbwebdialogs

I want to set the privacy of the wall post on my friends wall to SELF.

so that only he can see it, i know it is possible because there is a property, but there is no where documented how to achieve this.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

this is the code that i use:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     toStr, @"to",
     @"{'value': 'SELF'}", @"privacy",
     @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
     @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
     @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
     @"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
     nil];

    //NSLog(@"params %@", params);
    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
     ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or publishing a story.
             NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             } else {
                 // Handle the publish feed callback
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Share button
                     NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                      @"Posted story, id: %@",
                                      [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                     NSLog(@"%@", msg);
                     // Show the result in an alert
                     success();
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
```

But when i look in the GRAPH api this says:

```
"privacy": {
          "value": ""
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This. May be this Helps.

```
NSDictionary *privacyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"SELF",@"value",
                   nil];
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSString *privacyJSONStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:privacyDict];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"my message", @"message",
                   privacyJSONStr, @"privacy",
                   nil];
```

Set the objectofkey **(value,friends,networks,allow,deny)** of dictionary privacyDict according to your use

```
NSDictionary *privacyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"CUSTOM",@"value",
                   @"SOME_FRIENDS",@"friends",
                   @"[comma separated friends id]",@"allow",
                   nil];
```

Comment: How i can import SBJSON?